# What is $ \mathcal{P} \mathrm{er} (X) / \mathbb{Q} $?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, galois-theory, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

In the [following link](http://user.math.uzh.ch/ayoub/PDF-Files/periods-GKZ.pdf)$^{[1]}$, page $2$, we find the following question :

> Let $X$ be a smooth $ \mathbb{Q} $ - variety and let $\mathcal{P} \mathrm{er} (X)$ be the subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ generated by the image of the
>   pairing $(3)$. What is the transcendance degree of the finitely generated extension $ \mathcal{P} \mathrm{er} (X) / \mathbb{Q} $ ?

**My questions are** :

What is explitcitly, the definition of the set : $ \mathcal{P} \mathrm{er} (X) / \mathbb{Q} $ ? Is it defined by : 
$$ \mathcal{P} \mathrm{er} (X) / \mathbb{Q} =
\left\{ \ P \left( \int_{ \gamma_{1} } \omega_1 , \dots , \int_{ \gamma_{m} } \omega_m \right)    \;\middle|\;
 P \in \mathbb{Q} [t_1 , \dots , t_m ] \ \right\} $$ 
and if it's right, what is $m$ ? why ?

Why is $ \mathcal{P} \mathrm{er} (X) / \mathbb{Q} $ a finitely generated extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

$^{[1]}$ *Periods and the conjectures of Grothendieck and Kontsevich–Zagier* by Joseph Ayoub (Universität Zürich, Switzerland)

Comment: Same question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247799/what-is-explicitly-mathcalp-mathrmer-x-mathbbq?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you write in the above is the subalgebra of periods. To get $\text{Per}(X)$, you need to pass to the field of fractions, i.e. make every nonzero period invertible.

The finite generation of the extension $\text{Per}(X)/\mathbb{Q}$ follows from the finite generation of the subalgebra of periods which follows from bilinearity of the pairing$$(\gamma, \omega) \to \int_{\gamma} \omega$$and the fact that $\gamma$ and $\omega$ vary in a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.